# Using formulas in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm having a problem which I can't solve.

I want to count number of occurrences of multiple cells fulfilling a given criteria. Its something like this-

Da  Ex  Av  Da  Ex  Av  Da  Ex  Av
80  55  68  50  24  37  74  65  70

"Da", "Ex" and "Av" stands for Daily, Exam and Average respectively.
In the given row, a candidate, say "A", achieved qualifying "Average" marks of 68 and 70, whereas A did not achieve the qualifying marks (less than 50) in one instance; A got only 37.

How do I count, or display, in one cell the number of times A passed the qualifying marks of 50, which should be 2, in the row?

Comment: You might find the [`COUNTIF()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php) or [`COUNTIFS()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php) functions to be of interest

Comment: You mean to say that you want to count number of Occurrences  for Grade A, Average & others, Y don't you share some sample data with us !

Answer (score 1):

*I'm sure that you are looking for this:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get the Result in Cell `C2` write this formula & fill down:

`=IF(B2>70,"Qual.",IF(AND(B2>=60,B2<=70),"AVG",IF(AND(B2>=50,B2<=60),"Nqua","Out of Rng")))`

- To count the Results in Cell `B11` write this formula & fill Right then
  Down.

`=COUNTIFS($A2:$A8,"="&$A11,$C2:$C8,"="&B$10)`

**Note:**

- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.
- You can modify the GRADINGS since I've used the brief info provide in
  OP.